# Devise + Omniauth [WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, csrf, omniauth

I am getting this warning

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

immediately before my callback action runs, i.e.

```
Started GET "/users/auth/open_id?openid_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid" for 98.xxx.xx.xx at 2011-09-12 16:26:02 -0400
Started GET "/users/auth/open_id/callback?openid_url=https%3A%2%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts ... etc ... etc
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#open_id as HTML
Parameters: {"openid_url"=>"https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Entering Users::OmniauthCallbacksController, omniauth_login
```

There is no warning for requests coming directly from the browser.  I am using rails 3.1, devise 1.4.5, omniauth 0.2.6.

Ideas on how to address this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Turning off protect_from_forgery worked for me.

Comment: can you be more specific? where / how do you turn this off? only for openid auth? otherwise it sounds like it might cause a potential security hole...

Comment: You should only be doing this if you **know** what you're doing. And if you're about to turn off `protect_from_forgery` based on a StackOverflow answer, you **don't know** what you're doing!!